# Recreate CSS effects in Blender?

Tags: animation, svg

I would like to do something like stroke-dashoffset in blender. You can see what I mean exactly here:

https://svgartista.net/

Being able to define fill/stroke gradients and stroke-strength is a must.

Ist there a tutorial I could use?

Comment: Hello, could you rephrase you question so it is immediately understandable which effect exactly you want to achieve ? You can embed images and screenshots in your post. Have you explored grease pencil and line art modifier ?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.